# two jobs in one single spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, jobs

This is my problem:

I want two jobs configured in the same spring batch. There are 2 totally different tasks(jobs - read-process-write) I want to perform based on the arguement that I pass from the command line.

a) Is it possible to have something like this in the same batch config file?

```
<batch:job id="job1">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="reader1" writer="writer1"
            processor="processor1" commit-interval="1">
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:job>
<batch:job id="job2">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk reader="reader2" writer="writer2"
            processor="processor2" commit-interval="1">
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
 </batch:job>
```

b) If yes, how because when I try that this is what I get:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 48 in XML document from class path resource [hefo-job.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'batch:tasklet'.

Comment: have you tried define each job in a separate xml file?

Comment: Hi, yes I did and I get the same error.

Comment: check if you are using correct xmlsm definition and batch namespace. Else post full xml

Comment: I am unable to post the full xml because of limitation of my profile here, but I am sure I have used the correct namespace because I am trying to add to the existing running batch. And this tag is recognized properly. It throws an error only when I try to put another job bean.

Comment: Hi, I figured out the issue, it was silly, I declared tasklet tag "not wrapped" in the step tag :P